# Java regex replaceAll not working

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

regex not working as wanted

Code example:

```
widgetCSS = "#widgetpuffimg{width:100%;position:relative;display:block;background:url(/images/small-banner/Dog-Activity-BXP135285s.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0; height:220px;} 

someothertext #widgetpuffimg{width:100%;position:relative;display:block;}"

newWidgetCSS = widgetCSS.replaceAll("#widgetpuffimg\\{(.*?)\\}","");
```

I want all occurrences in the string that match the pattern "#widgetpuffimg{anycharacters}" to be replaced by nothing

Resulting in newWidgetCSS = someothertext

Comment: I'm confused...are you saying the result of "someothertext" is what you desire, or what you're currently getting?  Because I get "someothertext" as the result.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me; although I wasn't sure how to edit it to make it legible. I don't think you need the grouping around the `.*?` though.

Comment: same here, i am also getting `" someothertext "` as the output.

Comment: Sorry all It works as intended in my real code I was lacking the last curly braces that I included in the example above. Will remove the post. Thanks for all input as it verified that it should work as written and I had to look at the real code.

Comment: Mark an answer (possibly your own) as solution instead of appending "SOLVED" to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: After edit of question

I think the regex is working properly according to your requirements if you are escaping your `{` as mentioned below. The exact output I am getting is `" someothertext "`.

It has to be `newWidgetCSS = widgetCSS.replaceAll("#widgetpuffimg\\{(.*?)\\}","");`
You need to use `\\{` instead of `\{` for escaping `{` properly.

Comment: ? I am escaping with double backslashes

Comment: This was a misunderstanding due to the OP not formatting the code in the question properly.

Comment: @jalmen in your first version of the question it was showing single backslash. editing the answer now.

Comment: @Narendra Also you don't need to escape } :)

Comment: @FailedDev I think in java you need to escape `{` to match a literal `{`. Please check.

Comment: @Narendra A yes you are right, although my tool tricked me :)

Comment: @FailedDev I see. I am not a big fan of Java's regex implementation. I run into stack overflows every now and then :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?s)\\s*#widgetpuffimg\\{.*?\\}\\s*", "");
```

**Explanation :**

```
"\\s" +                // Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   "*" +                 // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"#widgetpuffimg" +    // Match the characters “#widgetpuffimg” literally
"\\{" +                // Match the character “{” literally
"." +                 // Match any single character
   "*?" +                // Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
"}" +                 // Match the character “}” literally
"\\s" +                // Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   "*"                   // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

As an added bonus it trims the whitespace.